# ls command does not work in the Program written in C(shell script)

Tags: c, linux, shell

```
void main() {
    char *args[MAX_LINE];
    char arg1[MAX_LINE/2] = "\0";
    char arg2[MAX_LINE/2] = "\0";
    printf("ubos>");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(arg1, sizeof(arg1), stdin);
    arg1[strlen(arg1) - 1] = '\0';
    fgets(arg2, sizeof(arg2), stdin);
    arg2[strlen(arg2) - 1] = '\0';

  abc:  
    printf("You typed: %s %s\n", arg1, arg2);
    fflush(stdin);
    args[0] = arg1;
    args[1] = arg2;
    args[2] = '\0'; 

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Vlue of arg[%d] =%s\n", i, args[i]);
    }

    if (strcmp(args[0], "ls") == 0) {
        execvp(args[0], args);
        goto abc;
    } else
    if (strcmp(args[0], "ps") == 0) {

    }

    printf("Something is not correct...\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

when I run this code with `ls` command this is the result. I don't know what is the problem with this code. When I run this code to execute another `.c` file it execute perfectly but when I try to use `ls` or `ps` command it does not let me use it and throws the error.

I have one more question why this `goto` does not working in this program .

```
ubos>ls

You typed: ls 
Vlue of arg[0] =ls
Vlue of arg[1] =
Vlue of arg[2] =(null)
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
```

so here is my mistake and can you give me some advise on how to use **exec** command and its different types.

Comment: Doesn't this output give you a clue: `Vlue of arg[1] =`? You are providing an empty string to `ls` as a parameter. That is, you are runnning `ls ''`. Run that command manually and you will see the same result. You should not be hard coding two arguments.

Comment: what if i want to execute two words arguments. I also want to execute some .c file . so that's why there are two arguments.

Comment: But that's not what you are testing. `ubos>ls`. That has no args to the `ls` command.  So your shell needs to handle zero arguments (one word). And you can't do it just by blindly setting the second arg to an empty string (`args[1]=arg2;`).

Comment: can you give me some code what can i do over here to pass two arguments or one argument.

Comment: I've pointed out the problem. Now how about you give it a go yourself first instead of just asking for the code?

Comment: i have written one test1.c code. if i type ./test1 it runs succesfully

Comment: Well that's probably because `test1` doesn't care about any of the args (or it can handle empty strings) so it doesn't matter if the args are wrong. But it does matter to `ls` what the exact parameter value is.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to put the `\0` explicitly in the string. Just write `char arg1[MAX_LINE/2] = "";` to initialize it to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If they don't provide an argument, set that argument in `args` to `0`. Then `ls` won't receive an empty string as its first argument, it won't get any arguments at all.

```
args[0] = arg1;
if (strlen(arg2) == 0) {
    args[1] = 0;
} else {
    args[1] = arg2;
    args[2] = 0;
}
```

You also need to check for this in the loop that prints all the arguments.

```
for(i=0;i<MAX && arg[i];i++)
{
    printf("Value of arg[%d] =%s\n",i, args[i]);
}
```

Comment: it showing me the segmentation falult when i enter ls as argument

Comment: The loop that prints the value of each argument needs to stop when it gets to the end.

Comment: thank you.  if (strlen(arg2) == '\0')
 {
      args[0] = arg1;
   args[1] = '\0';
 } 
 else 
 {
  args[0] = arg1;
      args[1] = arg2;
      args[2] = 0;
 }

Comment: Why do you use `'\0'` instead of `0` when it's a number or pointer, not a character?

Comment: `'\0'` is a null character. It's not usually used when you want an integer or pointer.

Comment: argument is the number so it should be null or it should have some character. If i write  args[1] = 0  it will save 0 as the value of args[1].

Comment: That's what you want, since `0` indicates the end of the arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please tell me will goto statement will work over here??

Comment: I was using goto statement after executing the arguments. but it was not working.

Comment: `execvp` replaces the current program with the program you're executing. Unless it gets an error, nothing after that executes. If you want your program to continue, you need to fork a child process to execute the program. The parent process should use `wait()` to wait for the child to finish, then the `goto` will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (strlen(arg2) == '\0')
    {
         args[0] = arg1;
         args[1] = '\0';
    } 
    else 
    {
        args[0] = arg1;
            args[1] = arg2;
            args[2] = 0;
    }
for(i=0;i<MAX && args[i];i++)
    {
            printf("Vlue of args[%d] =%s\n",i, args[i]);
    }
```

I was passing the blank space as the second argument. so it was showing me the error. Above code is the solution of my problem..